# What is this 2017 or earlier party-based, turn-based, iOS RPG set in a digital cyberspace?

Tags: ios, game-identification

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot of the game]

Platform: iOS, specifically an iPhone 5s

Genre: Party-based, turn-based RPG

Year: The screenshot is from 2017, pretty sure I had played it for about a year at that point, don't believe it had had any updates in several years but less confident about that.

Perspective: Global map for the overworld, portraits, and representation of enemy in combat (see screenshot for portraits during "cutscene")

Memorable Moments: The screenshot has a line of code that appeared in the game that I always wondered about. Otherwise, at one point the party meets a female researcher who doesn't want to help until she finds out they're working on an "infinity bug" or something along those lines.

Protagonists: The team starts with an "everyman hacker" kind of character, adds a fiery aggressive woman, an intimidating black guy who's actually a medic, a horny bard-esque character to get smacked down by the fiery woman, support character, etc.

Weapons/Equipment: It was hacking equipment (computers, interfaces, I think botnet was your HP?) but the actual combat was 100% RPG. Standard "Fight/Item/Defend/Run" interface, different attacks could stun or deal damage over time, etc.

Goal: Attempting to stop a shadowy cabal of some nefarious plot

Plot: Slowly recruiting a team of hackers to take on some shadowy cabal. News stories in the background were opponents of a bill (AI rights maybe?) being suicided.

Enemies: Portraits similar to the team except also had a background of where we were hacking.

Art: 2D art portraits, global map of the world with popups for random events, highlighted cities for shops/quests/news. Refer to the screenshot for portraits.

Setting: Earth, five minutes in the future. Everything was hacking focused so it was all webcams and remote access rather than actually traveling anywhere.

Environment: Digital cyberspace

Tone/Mood: Somewhat technological dystopia, some humor between the team, nothing extreme either way.

Comment: Google image search/reverse image search got nothing from my screenshot, possibly because that desktop is a single cutscene rather than standard gameplay

Comment: Have you searched through your purchase history of your apple account? It contains every app you've downloaded, including the free app. (Here's [guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204088), link is to apple's support page) It should contain this game, too.

Comment: As a point of trivia, the wallpaper in your screenshot is a stylized logo of the [LLVM project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM), which is the default compiler suite for MacOS and iOS.

Comment: Incidentally, that line of code is completely real and will actually work (kill all processes with "SYSWIPE" in their names or command line arguments) on most Unix-like platforms (i.e. just about anything that isn't Windows). You could *probably* ask [Unix.se] for an explanation of the individual components, if desired.

Answer (score 16):

It looks and sounds like **Nameless: The Hackers**.

A description as written [by one of the developers](https://www.reddit.com/r/iosgaming/comments/1nopxl/nameless_the_hackers_rpg_is_free_from_developer/):

> Nameless: the Hackers RPG is a cyberpunk adventure game that combines a visual novel style system (looks sort of like Phoenix Wright) with classic turn-based RPG battle mechanics with a twist. Battle through server rooms and elite hackers with specialized Bots, viruses and other romanticized computer science moves!
>
> The game plot is surrounded around a group of hackers who are hired to find a runaway computer scientist who has apparently uncovered something big, and it turns into a big conspiracy. The story is actually a little similar to the Snowden events (but we released the game before the whole thing came out). You'll just have to play it for yourself.

[image: screenshot from gameplay video]

This is a screenshot from [a gameplay trailer on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQuA9q3eVfc). The character highlighted in your screenshot is called [Tiny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGpvb.png). The use of HackChat and the desktop and its wallpaper and folders are likely part of a specific mission, which I have been unable to find in the linked video.

The game was released in 2013 ([source](https://www.ign.com/games/nameless-the-hackers)).
And, finally, [here](https://box-cat.com/site/games/nameless-the-hackers/) is the official site.